# Windows Phone development: How to make a custom class appear on a xaml grid?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I am new at Windows Phone development and I have a question regarding an app I am making.

I have a project that has classes called 'MainPage.xaml', 'MainPage.xaml.cs' and 'Character.cs'.
In my 'Character.cs' class I create an object that looks like a rectangle (if I made the class correctly) when instantiated. Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
//using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes;
using System.Diagnostics;

//Blue color: "#FF32C7FF"
//Green color: "#FF32FFE3"

namespace Manipulation
{
public sealed partial class Character : Control
{
    Path myPath = new Path();
    private TranslateTransform dragTranslation;
    private int gameStage;  // Determines what stage of game
    private int colorChoice;
    private int xCord = 200;
    private int yCord = 200;
    private int rHeight = 100;
    private int rWidth = 100;


    public Character()
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        SolidColorBrush characterColor = new SolidColorBrush();
        Rect myRectangle = new Rect(xCord,yCord,rWidth,rHeight);
        Path myPath = new Path();
        RectangleGeometry myGeo = new RectangleGeometry();
        GeometryGroup myGeoGroup = new GeometryGroup();
        Canvas myCanvas = new Canvas();
        //Grid MyGrid = new Grid();


        colorChoice = rand.Next(1,3);
        if(colorChoice == 1) // Represents blue color
        {
            characterColor.Color = Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb(100,50,199,225);
            myPath.Stroke = characterColor;
        }
        else // Represents green color
        {
            characterColor.Color = Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb(100,50,225,227);
        }
        myPath.StrokeThickness = 5;

        myGeo.Rect = myRectangle;
        myGeoGroup.Children.Add(myGeo);

        myPath.ManipulationDelta += Drag_ManipulationDelta;
        dragTranslation = new TranslateTransform();
        myPath.RenderTransform = this.dragTranslation;
        myPath.ManipulationMode = ManipulationModes.TranslateX | ManipulationModes.TranslateY;
        myPath.Data = myGeoGroup;           
    }

    private void Drag_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        dragTranslation.X += e.Delta.Translation.X;
        dragTranslation.Y += e.Delta.Translation.Y;
    }

    public int GameStage { get { return gameStage; } set { gameStage = value; } }
    public int CharacterColorNum { get { return colorChoice; } set { colorChoice = value; } }
    public int XCoordinate { get { return xCord; } set { xCord = value; } }
    public int YCoordinate { get { return yCord; } set { yCord = value; } }
    public int CharacterHeight { get { return rHeight; } set { rHeight = value; } }
    public int CharacterWidth { get { return rWidth; } set {rWidth = value;} }
}
}
```

What I want to be able to do is in my 'MainPage.xaml.cs' class I want to instantiate this Character class and have it place the rectangle it makes on my 'MainPage.xaml' grid. Could someone walk me through this since I am new add this?

Thanks

Comment: Google how to create a 'custom control' in windows phone.

Comment: Ok. I will read into that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an xmlns to it in you MainPage xaml:

```
xmlns:src="clr-namespace:Manipulation"
```

Then you can create an instance of it:

```
<src:Character/>
```

Here's a decent article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17830/Creating-and-consuming-a-custom-WPF-control

Answer (score 1):

if your custom control in other project don't forget add assembly in xmlns :

```
xmlns:src="clr-namespace:Manipulation;assembly=NAMEASSEMBLY"
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you change the default `Class` name and the `namespace` to your custom Class in `XAML`.

[Custom Base Page for Windows Phone](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jschaffe/archive/2011/03/03/creating-a-custom-base-page-for-windows-phone-7.aspx)